# Number of clusters varies rapidly

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm having some trouble with `FindClusters`.  I've got a list of 7,598 vectors, each with 10 real numbers generally between 0 and 1.  The number of clusters for the entire list is 1, using both the default distance function and the EuclideanDistance.  But if I slowly reduce the number of elements in my list I get strangely varying numbers of clusters.  This is my first use of clustering so it may just be that I don't know what I'm doing.

Below is my best attempt to display some of the information and results I see.

```
z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7598]]];
Length[z]
1   (I'm just including the result of Length in the code block)

z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7597]]];
Length[z]
1   

z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7596]]];
Length[z]
7

z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7595]]];
Length[z]
10

z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7591]]];
Length[z]
1         

z = FindClusters[t1[[;; 7590]]];
Length[z]
11

Column[t1[[7590;;]]]
{
{{0.0773395, 0.240442, 0.429185, 0.575374, 0.67981, 0.757002, 
0.819001, 0.860585, 0.884173, 0.894454}},
{{0.611247, 0.771605, 0.91659, 0.98912, 0.999001, 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1.}},
{{0.977517, 0.993049, 1., 1.001, 0.999001, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}},
{{0.152091, 0.326264, 0.506586, 0.64433, 0.759878, 0.868056, 
0.937207, 0.968054, 0.984252, 0.990099}},
{{0.526316, 0.888889, 0.968054, 0.980392, 0.985222, 0.98912, 
0.996016, 1., 1., 1.}},
{{0.665336, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}},
{{0.660502, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}},
{{0.915751, 0.960615, 0.980392, 0.990099, 0.995025, 0.997009, 
0.999001, 1., 1., 1.}},
{{0.660502, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}}
}
```

Comment: What are the distributions of the coordinate values over the different axis in your data? May be some axes have very narrow ranges (or few values) compared to others. What results do you get if you use the function [`Standardize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html)? Applying `Standardize` would make the distributions over the axes more comparable or compatible.